# files list file for package 'libgslcblas0:amd64' is missing final newline

Tags: apt, package-management

hello so I keep getting this error every time i try to install any packages with apt
for example i did apt install npm to get npm but i gave me this error files list file for package 'libgslcblas0:amd64' is missing final newline
so I tried to install something else but it gives me the same error if anyone can help it will be much needed as I need it for college

i have already tried a bunch of stuff but to no avail
inside the list file is E�"�) ") �; �;E H�; �; H"H& &�; H_"�;�; �; �;�; �;�; �; + G I+ "+ �; �;G + "J�; � J,  , �; �, "�;�;

Comment: Please add output of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgslcblas0*.list` to the question.

Comment: its just gibberish

Comment: Remove this file with `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgslcblas0*.list` and reinstall the package.

Comment: for starters, npm is bundled when you install nodejs so does not need to get installed explicitly ... install nodejs from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: @ScottStensland the issue is not npm related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove problematic file and

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libgslcblas0*.list
```

reinstall the package

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgslcblas0:amd64
```

Comment: i have i still get the same error